# Java ehCache, how to replace members

Tags: java, ehcache

I have a simple method that I have annotated for caching.

```
  @Cacheable(value = "devices", key = "#hardwareId", unless = "#result == null")
  public Device get(String hardwareId)
```

I have a mechanism to know when someone changes the underlying database. So that I know to Evict a member from the cache, so that the next call in will go back to the database.

```
 getCache().remove(hardwareId);
```

What I would like to do it REPLACE the element in the cache. The reason for this is that the call back to the database can take 1000ms & I'd like to not have that blip on the performance of the method.

As far as I can tell I have two options.

Option 1:

When I evict the member, call back into the service at that time.

```
 getCache().remove(hardwareId);
 service.get(hardwareId);
```

Option 2:

- Create an instance of 'net.sf.ehcache.bootstrap.BootstrapCacheLoader'
  that registers on startup the same class to be notified element
  being removed from a cache (notifyElementRemoved()).
- On @PostContruct get all methods annotated with @Cacheable. Create a Map of
  'cacheName' to Method instance (java reflection Method)
- When notifyElementRemoved() is triggered, uses the cache name to get the Method instance, with that invoke it to trigger the cache to be repopulated.

  ```
  Method method = map.get(cacheName);
  // Add magic here to get the service.
  Object serviceInstance = applicationContext.getBean("deviceService");

  if (Proxy.isProxyClass(serviceInstance.getClass())) {
    Proxy.getInvocationHandler(serviceInstance).invoke(serviceInstance, method, new Object[] {objectKey});
  } else {
    method.invoke(serviceInstance, objectKey);
  }
  ```

The downside of option 1 is that I have to go modify 30+ classes to put in the logic to call back into the service.

The downside of option 2 is that it's a bit complex, it feels like it would be good if ehCache could provide this feature. It knows what method it wrapped, it knows what the key/parameters were that called into this method.

The downside of both options is that there will always be a time when the cache does not contain the member & could cause a blip in performance.

My question is, does ehCache provide the feature I want or is there another mechanism out there to do REPLACEMENT of members in the cache with zero time of the cache being empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do option 2. Too complicated. In general, the way it goes is to have a `@Cacheable` and a `@CachePut` method. Why not using that?

```
@Cacheable(value = "devices", key = "#hardwareId", unless = "#result == null")
public Device get(String hardwareId)

@CachePut(value ="devices", key= "#hardwardId", unless = "#result == null")
public Device update(String hardwareId)
```

It should cleanly solve your problem.

BTW, you don't need to specify the `key`. It is implicit.